# Node JS - Compress responses except for specified file type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, compression

Having an issue using Node/Express compression and working with three.js.

I need to compress all .JPEG / .PNG but not any .GLB / .GLTF files within my project.

How would I go about configuring [Compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) to compress all files types with a file type exception. Would it be simpler to except a url to the folder containing those model files?

```
  app.use(compression( { filter: shouldCompress } ))

  function shouldCompress (req, res) {
    if (req.is('model/gltf-binary')) {
     // don't compress
     return false
   }
   // fallback
    return compression.filter(req, res)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using req.url i've managed to except the directory containing all models, but still struggling to find the correct method for excepting by file type:

```
function shouldCompress (req, res) {

if (req.url.includes('/models/')) {
// don't compress
return false
}
// fallback to standard filter function
 return compression.filter(req, res)
}
```